# Difficulty in plotting time series data on plotly

Tags: time-series, plotly

Here is a screenshot of the data:

[image: Here is a screenshot of the data]

And here is the output I am getting:

[image: Here is the output I am getting]

[This is the sort of plot I'm trying to get. This one is plotted using sns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGBjp.png)

This is the code I'm trying:

```
merged['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(merged['Date']
merged = merged.sort_values('Date')
fig=px.line(merged, x='Date', y='Weekly_Sales')
fig.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: `fig.update_xaxes(type='date')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @r-beginners Unfortunately, this hasn't worked. Same old problem. Thank you for replying